# Unclear Lambda expression to Array.Sort static function

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, lambda

I'm looking at an example on how to sort an int[] array with the Array.Sort function, where a lambda expression is passed as a `Comparison<T> (T x, T y)` delegate to sort all the integers in the array making it able to place odd numbers first. Here's the code :

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Array.Sort (numbers, (x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2 
    ? 0 
    : x % 2 == 1 
        ? −1 
        : 1);
// numbers array is now { 3, 5, 1, 2, 4 }
```

How is `Array.Sort()` actually calling x & y ? would anyone provide me a step by step explanation for that lambda ?

Comment: If you write `Func<int, int, int> f = (x, y) => x % 2 == y % 2 ? 0 : x % 2 == 1 ? −1 : 1;` then you can call it simply with `f(1, 2)`. It's calling it by just calling it. What kind of explanation do you aim for?

Comment: This lambda is `IComparer`, that will be called for each items in Array. `Array.Sort` itself can use different sort algorithms depending on array size. You can read it here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bzw8611x.aspx

Comment: I'm unclear as to what your actual question is. [The MSDN article on Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bzw8611x.aspx), as Sergey has linked to, shows that the method requires to be called as `Array.Sort(what, how)`, where `what` is your array and `how` is the `IComparer<T>` method which will be called by `Array.Sort` several times to compare pairs of values (here, `x` and `y`) during the sorting process to put them in the correct order. Is that the explanation you wanted, or was it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Int32.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the sorting method that this lambda expression is replacing. 
Normally, we'd have:

- `x < y`: return -1
- `x == y`: return 0
- `x > y`: return 1

Instead, we have:

- x odd, y even: return -1
- x odd, y odd OR x even, y even: return 0
- x even, y odd: return 1

Since the elements in the sets `{1, 3, 5}` are equal and `{2, 4}` are equal, you're at the mercy of the sorting algorithm used for the exact order of the final set.  The sorted list will have the form `{odds, evens}`, but the orders of those sublists will depend on the algorithm.  Per MSDN, [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses Insertion sort if the array has fewer than 16 elements.

When I do this, the order I get back is `{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}`, which is what I would expect, not `{3, 5, 1, 2, 4}`

UPDATE:
It was pointed out in the comments that `x % 2 == -1` for negative odd integers, which means that the above needs some reworking for the general `int`. (I apologize, but my math background means I think of mod as an unsigned value.)

- x odd, y even OR (x odd, y odd, x > 0 > y): return -1
- (x odd, y odd, same sign) OR x even, y even: return 0
- x even, y odd OR (x odd, y odd, x < 0 < y) : return 1

This will mean that we end up with a list of the form `{positive odds, negative odds, evens}`.

Comment: Actually, since this comparer method is not transitive, or reflexive, the sorting algorithm is not required to actually work at all.  It is within it's rights to just throw an exception and refuse to sort anything.

Comment: @Servy: I believe you are mistaken.
It is reflexive:  `(a, a) == 0` since
`a % 2 == a % 2` for any integer `a`.
I also don't think it is required to be transitive. String.Compare doesn't seem to need to be, per bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774540/string-compare-is-broken-in-net-4-0-and-4-5).

Comment: It's reflexive *if both values are even*.  It is not reflexive when they are both odd.  Yes, it is important that it be transitive.  If A > B and B > C then the sorting algorithm expects that A > C.  If A > B, B > C, and A == C then these expectations are violated.  Of course, in reality most of these sorting methods don't actually throw exceptions, they just produce an undefined ordering, but as their preconditions are violated, they are certainly within their rights to, and the output isn't really something that should be used.

Comment: @Servy: Counterexample?  Reflexive means that `a == a` for any value.  Since `a % 2 == 1` for odds, `a % 2 == 1 == a % 2` _for any integer_. Maybe I'm horribly mistaken and missing the obvious counterexample?
The other side  to this is that the relation is transitive, regardless.  We can't construct A > B and B > C.  If A > B, then A is even, B is odd (other cases would have A <= B).  If B > C, then B is even, C is odd, similarly.  Thus, we have a contradiction, since B % 2 == 0 and B % 2 != 0 (even and odd), so the case is impossible to construct. < will fail too, and so only == works.

Comment: @Timothy The counterexample are negative numbers: `-1 % 2 == -1` in C#. My guess is that's what Servy meant.

Comment: @Servy Maybe the comparison is not meant for negative numbers? Unless I'm mistaken, it's both reflexive and transitive on non-negative numbers.

Comment: @svick This could be written `(x, y) => (x % 2 == 0).CompareTo(y % 2 == 0)`, right?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen With that, the sort order would be odd negative, all even, odd positive. That order doesn't make much sense to me, but at least it's well-defined.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, the sort order there would be odd, even, which is likely the intention of the original lambda expression, with better readability.  Likely svick read `(x % 2).CompareTo(y % 2)`.

Comment: @svick I left out x < 0, but it doesn't matter for reflexivity. Regardless, our equivalence classes are the evens, positive odds, and negative odds.  For any two numbers x, y both in any of the three sets,  `x % 2 == y % 2` regardless, so x ~ y and reflexivity holds.

Transitivity works too, but it is important to realize that the sorting here is not on the standard integers that we're used to.  3 is equivalent to 491 in this strange universe, and -1 to -523973.  Sorting by this will work, but not in the way that is generally expected, since it will sort by the three equivalence classes.

Comment: @svick Read again. I had `== 0` and `0` is not signed (`Int32`). I exploited `bool.CompareTo(bool)`. It considers `false` less than `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison function type `(T, T) => int` is more general-purpose, but it can be a nuisance in some common cases. The lambda expression in your question is sorting numbers based on their values modulo 2, but the way it is written doesn't make that clear.

If you want to compare items based on some key, you can do that using the following helper method.

```
public static class Functional
{
    public static Func<T, T, int> KeyComparison<T, K>(Func<T, K> key)
        where K : IComparable<K>
    {
        return (x, y) => Comparer<K>.Default.Compare(key(x), key(y));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Array.Sort(numbers, Functional.KeyComparison(x => x % 2));
```

This sorts your numbers in the same way as before, based on their value modulo 2, but in a way that is more legible.

Comment: This isn't answering the question at all.  On a site note, this key comparer doesn't support comparing null values, performs the site  selector multiple times per item (which becomes quite relevant if it is either computationally expensive, performs side effects, or is not deterministic).

Comment: @Servy The `IComparable<T>` interface doesn't support comparing `null` values, because `this` is never `null`. I'm well aware this calls the selector (`key`) multiple times per element. The `Array.Sort` method (or any taking a `Comparison<T>`) makes that somewhat of a necessity. (Yes, you *can* get around it by doing memoization.)

Comment: You can trivially change the code to support `null` values by using `Comparer<T>.Default`.